# Fix "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" for Office365 API

Tags: node.js, authentication, office365, office365api

I'm working on this example code found here on github [nodejs-connect-rest-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-rest-sample) it starts a server on port `3000`. Then redirects to microsoft to login.

[image]

And this screen to provide access to the app.

[image]

Then this is the page microsoft redirects back to.

[image]

Here's the error in text form.

```
403 Forbidden

{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "6fca4864-c043-4aa6-b312-39cbe2ae4c41",
      "date": "2017-08-04T17:42:04"
    }
  }
}
Error: Forbidden
    at Request.callback (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/nodejs-connect-rest-sample/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:675:11)
    at /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/nodejs-connect-rest-sample/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:883:18
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/nodejs-connect-rest-sample/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:16:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I've tried digging through the Office 365 dashboard to provide access to my developer account. I found this screen that says I'm a "Global administrator".

[image]

How can I get access?

Answer (score 0):

You should be consenting to more permissions than "read calendar" and "sign in." All of the required permissions are here (in the scope parameter): https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-rest-sample/blob/master/utils/config.js
And you shouldn't be consenting to Calendar.Read, but in your screen shot it appears that you are.
Did you change the values in the scope parameter of the config.js file?